# Question on supremum proof

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-explanation

My textbook has the following half proof for a supremum:

An upper bound u of a nonempty set S in R is the supremum of S iff for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists an $S_{\varepsilon} ∈ S$ such that $u - \epsilon  < s_{\epsilon}$

(1) If u is an upper bound of S that satisfies the stated condition and if v < u then 
we put $\epsilon = u-v$.

(2) Then $\epsilon > 0$, so there exists $s_{\epsilon} ∈ S$ such that $v = u - \epsilon < s_{\epsilon}$.

(3) Therefore v is not an upper bound of $S$ and we conclude that $u$ = sup $S$

I'm pretty confused about (2), what does "$s_{\epsilon} ∈ S$ such that $v = u - \epsilon < s_{\epsilon}$" mean exactly? I can't seem to contextualize this line, if anyone could put this proof in layman terms that would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the assumption that an upper bound u of a nonempty set $S$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is the supremum of $S$ iff for every $ε>0$ there exists an $s_\epsilon \in S$ such that $u−\epsilon<s_\epsilon$.

In, (1), you assume $u$ satisfies the RHS of this statement. If $v < u$, then $u - v > 0$.
From our assumption, we know something about numbers $\epsilon > 0$. Hence, if we take $\epsilon = u - v > 0$, then we know from our assumption that there exists an $s_\epsilon \in S$ such that $u - \epsilon < s_\epsilon$. Note that since $\epsilon = u - v, u - \epsilon = u - (u-v) = v$. Hence, $v < s_\epsilon$, hence $v$ is not an upperbound of $S$.

Comment: Ok I think I'm starting to understand. If we take $v < u$, and subtract v from both sides we get $0 < u - v$ however we can equate $u - v$ to $\epsilon$. We then substitute $u - v$ into the assumed equation $u - \epsilon < s_{\epsilon}$ which gives $ v < s_{\epsilon}$ proving v cannot be an upper bound because v has to be greater than the set to be an upper bound

Comment: Yes, the fact that $v < u$ implies that $u - v > 0$, hence we can take $u - v = \epsilon > 0$ because we assumed that for *any* $\epsilon > 0$ we can find such an $s_\epsilon$.

Comment: Wait sorry, one last question, why does proving that v is not an upper bound, make u the supremum?

Comment: I made it more confusing with my last comment I think, so let me repeat my comment. You are given an upper bound u, THEN u is a supremum iff $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists s_\epsilon \in S : s_\epsilon > u - \epsilon$. You start with an upper bound $u$ and assume the RHS, then prove that $u$ is the *lowest* upper bound, i.e. supremum.